# Marionette js collection subsets

Tags: collections, filtering, marionette

Let's say I have a live chat user list.  Users are entering and leaving the list as they log in and out of my app.  A collection containing user models is constantly being updated and the view to which it is bound, a CompositeView in my case, reflects this.  This is working well.

I'd like to offer a radio button option above the list that allows the user to see subsets of the list.  I'll use color to illustrate.

Some users are red some are yellow and some are blue.  I can't seem to find my way to a clean solution for taking a user color selection and filtering the list accordingly.  The added complication of the live, dynamic nature of the list is throwing me off.  The list is never settled.  Users can come and go and can also change colors. Red users can turn yellow, yellow users can turn blue and so on.  If the yellow filter is on and Johnny turns from red to yellow, he should pop into the list.  If a minute later he turns red, he should leave the list.  If you switch the radio selector to red, you should see Johnny in the list again.

The only solution I'm seeing is multiple collections, manual maintenance of the collections (removal and additions as people change colors) and rebinding and display of the view as the color radio button selection changes.

Am I on the right track or is there a cleaner way to do this?  Is there a way to do it with one collection?

**UPDATE:**  Trying the upgrade to the latest version of Marionette js per the post below.  Upgrade [breaking stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188749/marionette-js-upgrade-1-x-to-2-x-breaks-my-dynamic-jquery-ui-tab-control).  When I work that out I'll try to get back to this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Marionette CollectionView.Filter](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-filter) :

> CollectionView allows for a custom filter option if you want to prevent some of the
>   underlying collection's models from being rendered as child views.

Since CompositeView extends from CollectionView you should have the same methods available.

Your filter method would look something like this :

```
filter: function (child, index, collection) {
  return _.contains(this.model.get('current_colors'), child.get('color'));
}
```

Now you need to detect when items change color. You could either base it on the model changing (with [collectionEvents](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.compositeview.html#modelevents-and-collectionevents)) or the view triggering an event.

```
collectionEvents: {
  "change:color": "render"
}
```

And finally also trigger off of when the radio button changes :

```
modelEvents : {
  "change:current_colors" : "render"
}
```

(alternately, just listen for the radio button change event).

Some of that would change based on how your current 'colors' are saved, but I think you get the point.

Comment: Sidenote : If rerendering the whole list on every change gets too slow, I would look into using this marionette virtual-dom plugin (https://github.com/tiagorg/marionette-vdom) before manually manipulating the dom to hide and show elements.

Comment: Also I should note that the filter method isn't available in 1.8.3 (which I saw you reference elsewhere) so you would need to update to at least 2.4.0 to have it available, but I would encourage you to update if possible.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the upgrade to 2.4.  Ugghhh...  Guess I have to give it a shot.  Let me give a try and report back. This could take a little bit.  I say again, ugghhh...

Comment: It's pretty easy if you use this tool : https://github.com/marionettejs/Marionette.Upgrade (update manually to 1.8.8, verify everything works, run the tool, then update to 2.4.x)

Comment: Yeah, been looking at that tool.  I'm not a python guy so I have to read up on that to run the tool.  Gonna try today. Triple ugghhh...

Comment: Upgrade not so good.  Breaking stuff,  most notably a dynamic tab control. Have to make a separate post.