# Marionette js upgrade 1.x to 2.x breaks my dynamic JQuery UI tab control

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, marionette, collectionview

After an upgrade from version 1.8.8 to 2.4.1 my dynamic tabs control broke.  The new Marionette won't let me do something that the old Marionette would.

A JQuery UI tab control expects a certain UI structure. At the core, it essentially wants an unordered list inside a container.  Like this:

```
    <div id="tabs-container">


        <ul id="tabs">//this guy should have li's inside it.  They'll become tabs.
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-content">
        </div>


    </div>//end #tabs-container
```

If you call $("tabs-container").tabs() in your JavaScript, it will turn all of that stuff into a tab control with the li items inside the #tabs ul becoming your tab headers.  Here's the key.  It doesn't want the li items to be **wrapped** by anything, like a div.  It wants the li's directly inside the ul.

Marionette wants to wrap stuff.  And that's my problem. If I have a view render those li's inside the ul, the view wants to wrap it's output in a div.  That messes things up.

In the old Marionette I used the view's "el" property to dump the view's output directly into the ul.  Like this:

```
    var TabCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView: TabChildView,
        el: $("#tabs")
    });
```

The new marionette doesn't like that.  It says that's putting the parent (the #tabs container) inside the new child element when it goes to appendChild.  Here's the error:

"Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent."

I'd like to rework this the right way for the new Marionette but am a bit stuck.  How do I get closer to where I need to be?

**UPDATE:** In studying this a bit I see that I could pull the ul inside the view generation.  So I wouldn't define the ul as a region into which a collection of li's is rendered.  Then the problem becomes what DOM element will assume the role of region containing my tabs control.  I'm wondering if this is a use case for the "Layout" component and if this would be a more solid approach.

If you think about it, a tab control is really two regions - one for the tab headers and one for the content divs associated with each tab.  Two related regions requiring coordinated construction and display?  A job for a Layout?  Am I thinking right here?  I'm looking to organize this optimally in solving it.

**MORE ANALYSIS:**

What I'm doing up to this point is placing a tabs container in my DOM and then dynamically rendering the tabs in it.  Maybe what I should be doing is creating the entire tabs control, container and all, dynamically.  In walking down that path there are basically three tasks that have to be completed:

1. .tabs() has to be called on some container. (when?)
2. A container has to be built.  It must have two regions in it: a #ul region for tab headers and a separate #div region for tab contents.
3. Collection views for both tab headers and and tab content have to be rendered

The questions that come out of that for me are:

1. How can I know when the two regions have been shown so that I can call .tabs() on their container?  onShow() maybe works for something like this where you have one CollectionView, but I need to know when two two CollectionViews have been shown.
2. How do I tell some structure (the outer tabs container) to render itself, and then to render two regions?  Is this what Marionette Layout does?

I'm just thinking out loud here really.  I'm reading about Layout now to see if this is a fit.  Looking for an indication that I'm heading down the right path.

**NEW CODE UPDATE: closer but still not working.  DOM structure rendered seems ok.  But tabs() initialization doesn't work.  Doing it on the fly during the construction of a LayoutView just doesn't seem to work.  The tabs css classes don't get added completely and the result looks nothing like a tab control.  I don't think this LayoutView approach will work with JQuery UI tabs.  I think what may be needed is to go back to the original approach, a ul region for tabs and another region for the content areas - the approach that used to work in Marionette 1.x.  Maybe there is a way to remove the wrapper around the collections. It's that extra wrapper that is breaking the control.  I can't think of another way to do this.**

```
    var TabLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        id: "tab-layout",
        template: Handlebars.compile(
            '<ul id="tabs">' +
            '</ul>' +
            '<div id="tab-content">' +
            '</div>' 
        ),

        regions: {
            tabsRegion: '#tabs',
            tabContentRegion: "#tab-content"
        },

        onBeforeShow: function () {
            var tabsRegion = this.getRegion('tabsRegion');
            var tabCollectionView = new TabCollectionView({
                collection: this.collection
            });

            var tabContentRegion = this.getRegion('tabContentRegion');
            var tabContentCollectionView = new TabContentCollectionView({
                collection: this.collection
            });

            tabsRegion.show(tabCollectionView);
            tabContentRegion.show(tabContentCollectionView);

            $('#tab-layout').tabs(); //Applies the tabs styling to the outer container (TabLayoutView)
        }            
    });


    //The tabs up top

    var TabItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        template: Handlebars.compile(
            '<a href="#tabs-{{id}}"><img src="../icon.png"></img> {{tabName}}</a>'
        )
    });

    var TabCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView: TabItemView,
        //el: $("#tabs") //Setting el like this used to work in Marionette js version 1.x.  Commented out now.   

    });



    //The tab content areas below the tabs

    var TabContentItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "div",
        template: Handlebars.compile(
             '<div id="tabs-{{id}}">' +
             '</div>'
        )
    });

    var TabContentCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView: TabContentItemView,
        //el: $("#tab-content") //Setting el like this used to work in Marionette js version 1.x.  Commented out now.
    });
```

**Above produces output below:**

```
    <div id="tabs-container">
        <div id="tab-layout" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <ul id="tabs" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                <div>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#tabs-4689e60e-1f96-4189-b0a2-6e8c4a2e6822"><img src="img.png"> Bob  Jones </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab-content">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="tabs-4689e60e-1f96-4189-b0a2-6e8c4a2e6822">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To build a collection view without div wrappings to produce:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

you only need to do this:

```
var MyListItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li'
});

var MyListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: MyListItem,
    tagName: 'ul'
});
```

Perhaps doing this and not needing to handle the other scenario will fix your problem?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I was not thorough enough in my description. My apologies. The ul is a region (the region containing the collection view).  As it's a region it must be in the DOM prior to showing the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will jive with your design concept, but you may consider making `#tabs-container` a region, in which, you would `.show()`

```
var MyListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({       
  childView: MyListItem, 
  tagName: 'ul',
  id: #tabs
});
```

This will replicate your DOM.

If you can't do this and you want to drop a list into the `ul#tabs` region, I can show you a hack to get around the `CollectionView` wrapper. Drop me a comment.

**UPDATE**
A LayoutView would solve all your problems.

1. To render the DOM dynamically you'd provide the LayoutView with the HTML in question as a template.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tabs-template">
   <div id="tabs-region"> 
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-content">
   </div>
</script>
```

```js
var TabLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView extend({
  template: _.template($("#tabs-template").html()),
  ...
});
```

2. The LayoutView `region` property would find the element in your template you want to use as a container, in this case

```js
region: {
   tabsRegion: '#tabs-region'
 }
```

You'd use this region to fever you CollectionView, for example. Like this:

```
onBeforeShow: {
  var region = this.getRegion('tabsRegion'),
      myListView = new MyListView; 

  region.show(myListView);
}
```

Using the MyListView we defined above.

3. If you're using Marionette v. 2.4.0+ then you can use the `onAttach` callback to ensure that your html is in the DOM. This callback was designed specifically to work with plugins that depend on elements existing in the DOM. Read [here](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.0/marionette.layoutview.html#use-of-the-attach-event) and see that entire section.
   Something like,

```js
onAttach: {
   this.$('#tabs').tabs()
}
```

Where `#tabs` is a child of `#tabs-region`, is the `ul` you rendered in that region.

**UPDATE** In the comments below the OP explained that he needs to know when both views are rendered. In general `Region.show()` is a synchronous process and thus, once both views are rendered we simply invoke

```
this.$el.tabs()
```

From the LayoutView. Like this,

```
onBeforeShow: function () { 
    var tabsRegion = this.getRegion('tabsRegion');
    var tabCollectionView = new TabCollectionView({ collection: this.collection }); 

    var tabContentRegion = this.getRegion('tabContentRegion'); 
    var tabContentCollectionView = new TabContentCollectionView({ collection: this.collection });

    tabsRegion.show(tabCollectionView);
    tabContentRegion.show(tabContentCollectionView); 

    this.$el.tabs();

}
```

If it happens that the views render asynchronously, then we would attach a listener to the views using the same handler. We would check the handler and once both views have checked in, we'd call `this.$el.tabs()`.

**UPDATE** The OP is looking for this DOM output:

```
<div id="tab-container" >
    <div id="tabs">
       <ul>
         <li class="active">
            <a href="#tabs-1" id="ui-id-1">tab1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="active">
            <a href="#tabs-1" id="ui-id-1">tab1</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-content">
       <div>
         <div id="tabs-1">
           <p>tab1 content elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>tab2 content elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

To do that we need to set up the views as follows:

```
var TabLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    id: "tab-layout",
    template: Handlebars.compile(
        // We want the outer #tabs el to be a div, and for it to hold a 'ul' (see
       // the TabCollectionView)
        '<div id="tabs">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="tab-content">' +
        '</div>' 
    ),

    regions: {
        tabsRegion: '#tabs',
        tabContentRegion: "#tab-content"
    },

    onBeforeShow: function () {
        var tabsRegion = this.getRegion('tabsRegion');
        var tabCollectionView = new TabCollectionView({
            collection: this.collection
        });

        var tabContentRegion = this.getRegion('tabContentRegion');
        var tabContentCollectionView = new TabContentCollectionView({
            collection: this.collection
        });

        tabsRegion.show(tabCollectionView);
        tabContentRegion.show(tabContentCollectionView);

        this.$el.tabs(); //Applies the tabs styling to the outer container (TabLayoutView)
    }            
});


//The tabs up top

var TabItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: Handlebars.compile(
        '<a href="#tabs-{{id}}"><img src="../icon.png"></img> {{tabName}}</a>'
    )
});

var TabCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: TabItemView,
    tagName: "ul"
});

//The tab content areas below the tabs

var TabContentItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    //Don't need 'tagName'. By default Backbone will create a div el for a View
    // Give the child contet div an id
    id: function () {
        return 'tabs-' + this.model.id;
    },
    template: Handlebars.compile(
         '<p><%=content%>' +  // assuming your model has a 'content' attr
         '</p>'
    )
});

var TabContentCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: TabContentItemView,
});
```

**Note**: Read the above carefully the changes to your original code are minor, but are commented.

Comment: I think this is the right path, but there is some work to do to make it happen.  See my updated comments above and let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the second task listed above happens - namely rendering collections in the tabs and tabs-content elements.  Wouldn't these elements have to be regions too?

Comment: Just picking this up after a long absence.  I have it all implemented but for some reason the myListView isn't picking up my itemView.  Only thing being rendered inside the <ul> is one empty <div> (not the <li>'s that are needed).  I have properly linked the itemView in via the childView tag in my CollectionView.  Hmmmm... Weird.

Comment: Posted above.  Thanks.

Comment: Think I see the issue.  The actual collection is not bound to the view.  I think I have access to it in the LayoutView.  Let me fix and see if it works...

Comment: Yup. I usually populate my collection in the parent LayoutView and on Promise success I show the view.

Comment: Better but still no go.  DOM structure rendered seems ok.  Jquery UI tabs styling not being applied completely though.  The ul got some stuff.  The tab-content div got nothing though.  Is there something bad about calling $('#tab-layout').tabs() in onAttach()?  This really isn't working out well.  The list is a dynamic user list.  Users are being added and deleted as they come and go from a session.  I don't think this LayoutView approach is suited for this.  Real shame.  Was so easy in 1.x.  Very difficult in 2.x.  Marionette js needs to be accommodating to plugins.  They're widely used.

Comment: What if you give `TabCollectionView` an `id` property of `#tabs` (change the region name that uses the same id), and `onAttach` run `this.$el.tabs()`?

Comment: No go.  "error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'". From what I understand you don't call tabs() on the TabCollectionView.  You call it on the outer container - the thing that is supposed to hold the tab buttons up top and the corresponding tab content areas.  In this case the outer container is "tab-layout".  Calling tabs() on that does produce a result.  Styling is added. Not all is added though.  Almost as if the tab content area is not available yet so nothing is applied to it.  I think we really have to know **BOTH** regions are ready.

Comment: Tried both approaches in update.  No go on either.  Each produces the same incomplete tabs() initialization.  The ul gets styling class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all".  The tab-content div gets nothing.  It's just a plain old div.  Also tried one other thing - onShown() in tabLayoutView.  Marionette js really just needs an option not to wrap content but rather target an existing container. This is what used to work - http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/k3Nzz/.

Comment: Robert if you inspect the generated HTML in your fiddle, both CollectionViews have a wrapper (one is a `<ul>` the other a `<div>`). I think something else is wrong.

Comment: The fiddle is actually somebody else.  I used it as an example.  Yeah I do see section wrappers around the two important elements.  Have no idea why that works.  The docs (http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/tabs/) clearly show unwrapped structures.  My original Marionette 1.x code works too.  It produces no wrappers.  Very confusing.  I'm stumped at the moment.  The only change I made in my code from Marionette 1.x to 2.x was the elimination of the setting of the CollectionView el property, like - el: $("#tabs"), because that line causes an error.  All I know is 1.x works and 2.x seems impossible.

Comment: The Marionette js version in the fiddle is 1.0.4.  My code (original post) works on 1.8.3.  It does not work on 2.4.1.  Sounds like a version 1.x / 2.x problem.  I really need features in 2.4.1

Comment: Right.  Just not with Marionette 2.x.  At least not yet.  I'm not seeing why.

Comment: Well, jQuery just cares about the DOM not any underlying framework your using to form your DOM. I think it's neither Marionette, nor jQuery. Maybe post your DOM output. Let's take a look at that. And if you updated your code, go ahead and post the latest.